# Full adder in haskell

Tags: haskell, boolean-logic

Haskell newbie here. I need some help with writing a function for a full adder. 
I've got the following:

```
xor :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
xor True False = True
xor False True = True
xor _ _ = False

fulladder :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool ->(Bool, Bool)
fulladder a b c =  c xor (a xor b) ++ (a&&b) || ((a xor b) && c)
```

and I'm getting the following error:

```
  * Couldn't match expected type `(Bool -> Bool -> Bool)
                                    -> Bool -> Bool'
                  with actual type `Bool'
  * The function `a' is applied to two arguments,
      but its type `Bool' has none
      In the first argument of `(&&)', namely `(a xor b)'
      In the second argument of `(||)', namely `((a xor b) && c)'
```

Comment: But your function does not return two elements?

Comment: I think you might be looking to `\`xor\`` (backticks needed to make it infix). As it is now you are applying `a` to two arguments, `xor` and `b`.

Comment: You currently implement a whole function, and then try to debug why it fails. You can make things much easier on yourself if you start small and build out. For example, `fulladder a b c = True ++ True` could be a good first dummy implementation: it fails, but it's much shorter and easier to look up. Once you've fixed that, you can expand to `fulladder a b c = (True xor True, True)`, and so on until you get to your full expression.

Answer (score 8):

The return type of your function is a **tuple**. Indeed:

```
fulladder :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool -> (Bool, Bool)
--                                   ^ 2-tuple
```

Now `(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]` concatenates **lists**. So this will definitely not work to construct a tuple. So the first error we resolve is:

```
fulladder :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool ->(Bool, Bool)
fulladder a b c =  ( c xor (a xor b) , (a&&b) || ((a xor b) && c) )
--                 ^ tuple syntax    ^                            ^
```

Next in Haskell you specify a function followed by the arguments. So `c xor a` won't work. You should use `xor c a` (or use backtics). So we should rewrite it to:

```
fulladder :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool ->(Bool, Bool)
fulladder a b c =  ( xor c (xor a b) , (a&&b) || ((xor a b) && c) )
--                   ^      ^ right order          ^
```

or alternatively:

```
fulladder :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool ->(Bool, Bool)
fulladder a b c =  ( c `xor` (a `xor` b) , (a&&b) || ((a `xor` b) && c) )
--                     ^   ^    ^   ^ backtics           ^   ^
```

Now the function generates:

```
*Main> fulladder False False False
(False,False)
*Main> fulladder False False True
(True,False)
*Main> fulladder False True False
(True,False)
*Main> fulladder False True True
(False,True)
*Main> fulladder True False False
(True,False)
*Main> fulladder True False True
(False,True)
*Main> fulladder True True False
(False,True)
*Main> fulladder True True True
(True,True)
```

Which is the correct result for the *output* and *carry* tuple.